# Ошибка преобразования значения varchar [RegisterId ]в тип данных int

Tags: c#, sql, asp

Делается проект на подобии социальной сети. Когда я пытаюсь вызвать список друзей, то получается следующая ошибка  "Ошибка преобразования значения varchar [RegisterId ]в тип данных int".
и перебрасывает на этот кусочек кода

```
  public static  class Database
{
    public static string connString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HeartBeatDB"].ConnectionString;


    public static DataTable GetData(string query)
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);


        conn.Open();

        sda.Fill(dt); //именно сюда

        conn.Close();
        return dt;
    }
```

Сама таблица в базне данных выглядит так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Думаю,что он ругается на RegisterId Из-за типа int. Но как исправить эту проблему?

Comment: Чему равен `query`?

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать в запросе сделать CAST(RegisterId as varchar), если не принципиально с каким типом вам потом работать используя RegisterId